# Как работает авторизация на Last.fm?

Tags: javascript, callback, md5, firefox-extension

Я пишу небольшое расширение для Firefox - скробблер Last.fm. В документации к API указан странный и непонятный мне метод авторизации. Необходимо получить ключ и сформировать http запрос в пределах JavaScript. Так же в документации указаны callback url, tokens и шифрование md5. Возможно для этого нужно подключать какие либо фреймворки. То что я находил в поисковиках - немного не то.

Буду благодарен если кто нибудь объяснит как это работает, или же даст ссылку на ресурсы где можно почитать по интересующим меня вопросам, можно на английском языке.
[Документация Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/api/webauth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализацию можно подсмотреть в опен-сорсном FoxyScrobbler ([scrobbler.js](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/360804/file/chrome/content/foxyscrobbler/scrobbler.js#L67)).

Для расширения Firefox вам больше подходит [API для "desktop" приложений](http://www.last.fm/api/desktopauth), а не для web-приложений, на которое вы дали ссылку:

- Web-приложение по определению - это что-то с публичным URL, открытое у пользователя в браузере. Поэтому процесс выглядит так:

  Веб-приложение перенаправляет браузер пользователя на страницу авторизации last.fm, сообщая в URL, что за приложение требует авторизации (`?api_key=xxx`).

  В результате успешной авторизации, last.fm направит браузер пользователя по указанному адресу web-приложения, который вы либо указываете как "callback URL" (`?api_key=xxx&cb=http://example.com`), либо на указанный при регистрации приложения URL.

  Серверная часть вашего web-приложения, получит запрос на этот callback URL (в котором, в частности, есть token, необходимый для дальнейшей работы с API last.fm)
- При авторизации для desktop-приложений возвращать пользователя со страницы last.fm некуда (у вашего приложения нет URL), поэтому API работает в обратном порядке:

  Вы сначала получаете token (запросом `auth.getToken` к last.fm), затем открываете браузер, чтобы пользователь мог подтвердить last.fm-у, что этот token авторизован (`?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&token=xxxxxxxx`)

  После успешной авторизации, вы можете им пользоваться, аналогично варианту для web-приложений.

Собственно, token в этой истории - это разовый случайный идентификатор, известный вашему приложению и last.fm. Вам он нужен, чтобы получить у last.fm другой случайный идентификатор (ключ сессии), который вы будете использовать для вызовов всех остальных API.

Какие вопросы у вас возникли про MD5 - не понимаю. На всякий случай: [Имитозащита на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0) (честно говоря, не знал, что оно так называется).

> Возможно для этого нужно подключать какие либо фреймворки.

Поскольку API у last.fm самопальный, фреймворки вам не помогут. Самое близкое, что можно использовать - FoxyScrobbler, на который я привел ссылку выше. Есть еще [библиотека для node](https://github.com/maxkueng/node-lastfmapi), но там сейчас в разделе "Authentication for Desktop Applications" написано *(Coming soon)*, что настораживает...